# In autocomplete how to display selected label but backend i want value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete, nodes

When I select label it is showing value while select,instead of this I want label should display in text box but backend i want to get value not label.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/xyz',
        type:'get',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data){
            var data=[];
            var arr=data;
            for( var i=0;i<arr.custdata.length;i++) {
                var obj={"value":arr.custdata[i].site_code,"label":arr.custdata[i].site_name};
                data.push(obj);
            }
            $("#siteid").autocomplete({
                source: data,
                minLength: -1,
            });   
        }
    });
```

Html

```
    <div class="uk-width-1-4"> 
    <div class="searchlabel">Site ID</div> 
    <input type="text" class="md-input md-input-success" name="siteid" id="siteid" />
    </div>
```

Comment: i think you are confused between label and textbox

Comment: I used this input tag,<div class="uk-width-1-4">
                                <div class="searchlabel">Site ID</div>
                                    <input type="text" class="md-input md-input-success"  name="siteid" id="siteid"  >
                            </div>

Answer (score 0):

You are confused between label and textbox.

Selected values are always shown in that `searchlabel` div.

```
<input type="text" class="md-input md-input-success" name="siteid" id="siteid" />
```

You get the selected value by

```
var selectedVal = $("#siteid").val();
alert("selectedVal=="+selectedVal);
```